# Where to find free Thailand stock recommendations and research?

Tags: online-tools, stock-analysis

I have a portfolio which consists of Thai stocks and I need inputs on how to re-balance them.

Where could I get free recommendation/research about Thai stocks?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

On what basis did you do your initial allocation of funds to each stock?   If you are 're-balancing' that implies returning things to their initial allocation.  You can do this without any research or recommendations.

If you started out with say 10 stocks and 10% of the funds allocated to each stock, then re-balancing would simply be either buying/selling to return to that initial allocation.  If you are contributing to the portfolio you could adjust where the new money goes to re-balance without selling.  Or if you are drawing money from the portfolio, then you could adjust what you are selling.

If on the other hand you are trying to decide if you want to alter the stocks the portfolio is HOLDING, then you have an entirely different question from 're-balancing'

Comment: This is a comment/question, not an answer.

Comment: It addresses the core of what he thinks he needs the info for, which is "I need inputs on how to re-balance them"  If that's really what he's seeking to do, then what I've said directly addresses that.